# create hyperlink for a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.msg = "Updated Successfully. Id: " +  $scope.id;
```

In the above code after successful creation of any data, message will be shown as "Updated Successfully. Id: 13456". I would like to make the ID as hyper link. I have tried...

```
$scope.msg = "Updated Successfully. Id: " + document.write( '<a href="#test_update/' + $scope.id + '" title="Click to view Details" target="details">' + $scope.id + '</a>');
```

But it's not working.Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Strict Contextual Escaping` in AngularJS. For this you need to inject `$sce` service in your controller.

**Controller**

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
.controller('AppController', ['$sce',
  function AppController($sce) {
    $scope.msg = $sce.trustAsHtml("Updated Successfully. Id: <a href='#test_update/" + $scope.id + "' title='Click to view Details' target='details'>" + $scope.id + "</a>");
  }]);
```

And use `ng-bind-html` to render this HTML in your template as a safe HTML.

**HTML**

```
<span ng-bind-html="msg"></span>
```

Comment: why is this recommended? isn't this complicating scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Or Simply You could do like

```
<a ng-href="#test_update/{{id}}">{{id}}</a>
```

in your case

```
<span ng-if="id">Updated Successfully:  <a ng-href="#test_update/{{id}}" title='Click to view Details' target='details'>{{id}}</a> </span>
```

Check Angularjs documentation for [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)